# Where does theme($row) get evaluated?

Tags: views

I am baffled by this line of code:

```
$work[$id] = $view->field[$id]->theme($row);
```

Does anyone know where `theme($row)` gets evaluated?

`$word[$id]` gets set to this emfield's url, "http://mysite.com/myvideo.flv", which is the value of both:

```
$view->field[$id]->last_render
$view->field[$id]->original_value
```

So I am guessing that `theme($row)` gets evaluated to either 'last_render' or 'original_value'.
But when I add debug code to print `theme($row)`, nothing gets printed.

Any ideas?

Here is the context in which this line of code appears, from views-view-swftools.tpl.php:

```
   foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {

          // Reset the work array
          $work = array();

          // Render each field in this row using the assigned handler
          foreach ($keys as $id) {
            $work[$id] = $view->field[$id]->theme($row);
          }
          ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [method call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), the `theme` method is invoked on the `$view->field[$id]` object. The method is likely [`views_handler_field::theme`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--handlers--views_handler_field.inc/function/views_handler_field%3a%3atheme/6) but it may have been overrided by the  `views_handler_field` subclass used for a particular field handler. Usually, the method will eventually ends up calling the [`theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6) function to use a defined theme function or template for the field (if this is a CCK field, a [formatter](http://drupal.org/node/92382) will likely be used).

Answer (score 0):

> But when I add debug code to print theme($row), nothing gets printed.

That's just because that function has no output.

Comment: But what does the function do?  And where does it do it?

Comment: That's variable, it's offered by drupal, see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6 - I suggest you trace that in a debugger session as you then can follow how the code gets executed. This is possible with Eclipse and xdebug for example.

Comment: Calls to theme functions generally look like theme('mythemer', ...), where the first argument is a string, and are implemented by the function theme_mythemer(...).  What I have never seen before, though, is a call to theme($row), where $row is an object, not a string.  I suspect this is specific to views.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a theme *method* on some views object, not the theme function().

Comment: Aha.  If I understand what you are saying, this bit of code finds the themeing method associated with `$view->field[$id]`, and then applies this themer to the particular row.  So my next question is:  where would I find the definition of the themeing method associated with a particular fieldtype, in views?  Would this be the field's display-method, as defined in the cck UI?

Comment: I don't remember that from top of my head. But you can `var_dump($view->field[$id])` and check the name of the object. Then search for the definition of it in the code.